# Navigate/open a HTML source stored in a variable in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, c#-3.0

Selenium webdriver can navigate to the given URL, couldn't find how to navigate/open a HTML source stored in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think there's an alternate to this, may be this can help someone. We can write the string(having html source) to a file and save as '.html like shown below:

```
 StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\temp.html");
            SW.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
            SW.Close();
```

Then we can open this with the webdriver(chrome for instance) like this:

```
ChromeDriver ChDriver = new ChromeDriver();
ChDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\temp.html");
```

Would be good to know if there is a direct way to do with the webdriver.